# Page back not working as expected on BinaryWrite

Tags: c#, asp.net, response.write

I have a home/main menu page. There's a link to the form. If you run the form with inputs, you get Excel output. If you click 'open' to open that output in the browser, the back-button takes you to the home/main menu.

Which is understandable, since if the form page is X.aspx, the binaryWrite that outputs the Excel doesn't really change that.

The problem is that if there's a postback, the back button takes you to the form page. This is inconsistent. If I run the page or a drop down causes a postback, I really want the back-button to take me to the form field, so that I can run the excel sheet again.

Things I've tried.

I tried adding a location header.

```
e.ContentFileName = "ELTFile.Output.xls";
```

Before the response.Writing ...

```
private void SendFileToBrowser(DownloadFileEventArgs e)
{
    if (!e.Cancel && e.FileObject != null)
    {
        this.Page.Response.Clear();
        this.Page.Response.ClearContent();
        this.Page.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("inline; filename={0}", e.ContentFileName));
        this.Page.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", e.FileObject.LongLength.ToString());
        this.Page.Response.AddHeader("Location", e.ContentFileName);
        this.Page.Response.ContentType = e.ContentType;
        this.Page.Response.BinaryWrite(e.FileObject);
        this.Page.Response.End();
    }
}
```

And I tried

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
```

As well as

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Server);
```

But basically, depending on whether or not I post back before I click the 'Submit' button to generate the Excel, I get the main menu (don't want) or the form page (want). I want the form page every time. Basically I want to tell the browser "I know it's not really a different page, but treat it that way, will ya please?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly add pages to a browser history.

You could make your application such that the form is always a page ahead of the excel output.

To do this, have a separate page to output the excel.
When you have the inputs to generate the excel, `Response.Redirect` to the generation page.
This will keep your input form in the browser history.

*Note: you could redirect to the same page too if you liked, but that would need you to track it.*

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to mark yours as the answer. I should have thought of it myself. But for some reason I got caught up in thinking I could manipulate the Response object into believing the 'before' and 'after' were two different pages. Thanks again.